# Python 3: Find Index of Square in grid, based on Mouse Coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

*This may have been asked before, but for my lack of correct English terms end up leaving me here. (I'm Finnish) This may be asked before, but what else could I have done?*

---

But I have pygame code, which renders partion of bigger 'map'. I want to have behaviour to 'click' a squre and 'select' it.

The broblem is, how do I find the index of image I am currently overlapping with mouse?

**Codelike close to what I have now**

```
#...setup code...
map = [[0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]
while:
    render()
    #render completely fills the screen with images based on map's objects
    mousepos=pyagem.mouse.get_pos()

    selectedMapSquare=???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to divide the absolute (screen) coordinates with the size of your squares. So, if the size of your squares is e.g. `32`, you can use something like

```
x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
# TODO: use a constant
w_x, w_y = x / 32, y /32
```

Now `w_x` is the index of the `x` axis, and `w_y` is the index of the `y` axis:

```
# TODO: bound/error checking
tile_under_mouse = map[w_y][w_x]
```